# Add active class and CSS to links <a> inside of buttons bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Hey guys I'm learning bootstrap/CSS while I design a website for a course.

[Heroku app](https://fierce-brushlands-63385.herokuapp.com)

Right now I have my header which is fine. There are some buttons, which have a `<a>` tag which covers all of them and that's all inside some divs and containers.

The inspector shows `<a>` tags. I made them as large as the buttons for click space, so I think I have to target these tags instead of the buttons.

I recently tried to completely overhaul the header and use the one from Bootstrap docs and did a jQuery script

```
$(function() {
 $('button').click( function() {
$(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
}); 
});
```

This changed the style for white background (my choice for active) but it didn't stay. As soon as the redirect happened it was gone.

Should I use :visited and then remove it as I think :visited is a property which doesn't change when I click links.

[Link to header file](https://github.com/mateomgj/private-events/blob/master/app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb)

[Link to CSS file](https://github.com/mateomgj/private-events/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss)

Here's the newly added CSS which I think would work, the path of all the classes to get to the `<a>` tags.

The header attributes are not relevant but wouldn't want to leave anything out.

```
header{
 text-align: center;
 padding-bottom: 0em;

/* SHOULD THIS WORK?  */
    .navbar  .container .btn-group button.active a{
    background-color: white;
}

}
```

EDIT Header HTML -> The `<a>` Tags have width: 100%; height: 100%; so I always clicked them instead of the buttons. Didn't know a better way

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
<div class="container">
<div class="btn-group">

    <button type="button "class="btn btn-lg"><%= link_to current_user.name, current_user %></button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg"><%= link_to "Log Out", root_path %></button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg"><%= link_to "New Event", new_event_path %></button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg"><%= link_to "All Events", events_path %></button>
```

I basically want something like Rift website

[Oculus rift](https://www.oculus.com/en-us/rift/)

Whether you are in Rift/Touch/Oculus Ready Pcs their formatting is different, they are bold and have a line underneath. I want that for my header but with white background instead.

Comment: I want the header to change to background-color: white. While I'm in that site, that is after I click the link, and I want it to stay that way until I go to another site. Neither of these are happening

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: You shouldn't mix nest an <a> inside a <button>, that might give you a start

Answer (score 0):

Are you searching for

```
a:focus {
    background-color:white;
}
```

EDIT

If you want a white background all the time after clicked in the link, you need to create a cookie

```
$(function() {
    // Check cookie
    if (document.cookie.indexOf("clicked") >= 0) {
        // Change header
        $('header').css('background-color', 'white');
    } else {
        // Create trigger
        $('button').click(function(){
            $('header').css('background-color', 'white');
            // Create cookie
            document.cookie = 'clicked=1;';
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: But I need to put the (a) inside the button class right? I did that and it didn't work. Also what about the jquery function as it targets button not (a)

Comment: No. A button have a state :focus too.

Comment: See my edit. This worked, but it instead changed the whole background white. I added the html so you can see how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you nested a `<a>` inside a `<button>`, but if I understood your question, this is what you need:

```
$(function() {
    $('button').click( function() {
        var nav = $('.navbar.navbar-fixed-top.navbar-inverse');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        nav.css('background-color', '#fff');
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I tried this but it did nothing. I think it's because I never 'click' a button as the < a> tags are on top of the button, that's why I nested it inside <button>